Inconsistent capitalisation for "Ask Question" button
The "Ask Question" button is shown with a capital 'Q' when you are on a question page, but with a lower case 'q' when on the main page.
This capital issue should be fixed.
If it matters, I'm using Vivaldi browser v7.0.3495.10, and I have tried forcing a full refresh of the page (Ctrl + F5).



I respect the fact that you saw this, there aren't enough people who care enough about textual correctness so this is not completely invisible to them. I absolutely hate the fact that you made me aware of it.

@Gimby I used to work on the UI part of our software in my previous assignment, and also review the documentation, so I guess this is some kind of habit for me to detect those inconsistencies. I'm glad I shared this minor annoyance with someone else :)

bingo, I'm also a documentation daddy. A rare breed.

@Gimby Thank you for making me aware of this :) There appears to be something not right between the people who work on SE to make it work and the people who work for SE who say what is presented.

This bug is now fixed it seems, any moderator that comes across this request can close it now I believe.
